# Should I be using a composite key for this table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

My database is going to store words, so the Word table is the most important. The Rhyme table lists which words a particular word perfectly rhymes with. It consists of three fields:

```
RhymeID - primary key.
WordID - foreign key linking to Word table
Rhyme - a non key integer which refers to a different record in the Word table.
```

E.g. 'cat' has WordID 009, 'bat' has WordID 014 and 'fat' has WordID 035, two records in the Rhyme table might look like this

```
RhymeId - WordId - Rhyme
001 - 009 (cat) - 014 (bat)
002 - 009 (cat) - 035 (fat)
```

The question is, should I make WordId a primary key to form a composite key with RhymeId? Do I need it to uniquely identify each record? I have no practical experience with databases, this one is still in the planning stage.

Comment: If I'm reading your schema correctly, it is different than what I would think to make. I would think you would have tables Word(word_id, word), Ryhme(rhyme_id, sound), and RhymeWord(word_id, rhyme_id). The RhymeWord key can then be a composite of the word_id and rhyme_id. The problem with how you set it up is how do you know that bat rhymes with fat without entering a bunch of "duplicate" data or writing the bat-fat query differently than the cat-bat query.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8334/13333

Comment: Probably a better question for the [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) SE site.

Comment: As @WuHoUnited points out you will need extra rows to link "bat" to "fat" but worse you will then need to add a second row with WordId and Rhyme reversed, and so on for *every* pair you identify.  This will get infeasibly large very quickly.

Answer (score 5):

First make it clear than `Rhyme` is also a FK

You should do either of the following:

- Make `RhymeId` the PK and create an **composite unique index** with `WordID`
  and `Rhyme` so no combination of two words appears twice.
- Get rid of `RhymeId` and make a **composite PK** with `WordID` and `Rhyme`

**I preffer the second** option because you need to keep only one index instead of two.

Comment: A many-to-many relationship table is the best place for a composite key.

Answer (score -1):

Two concepts from the DB design world apply here.  They are "natural keys" and "surrogate keys".  A natural key is that combination of columns, the values of which can be used to distinguish the row which contains them from all other rows in the table i.e. that combination of values is unique in the table.  Importantly these columns appear "naturally" in the user's understanding of the problem.  A surrogate key is a value invented to stand in for the natural key, usually for technical or performance reasons.  Once you create a surrogate key it is normal practice to use that as the foreign key in all other tables.

In your example "cat" wold be the natural key of the `Word` table and "009" is the surrogate key for that natural key.

So, for your `Rhyme` table the natural key would be WordID and Rhyme (yes, even though they are both themselves surrogate keys from another table) and `RhymeID` is the surrogate key.

If other tables will have a foreign key pointing back to `Rhyme` then I would definietly suggest giving it a surrogate key.  If it won't then the surrogate is 50% bloat for zero value in what is likely to be an exceedingly large table; I would suggest omitting it.

Comment: Why the downvote? Answer seems fine to me

Comment: Yes,  an explanation would be nice, please.